# Android NDK - Including prebuilt static libraries gives undefined reference errors

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am trying to build a shared library using a prebuilt static library. For some reason, building always fails giving `undefined reference` errors. If I add `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true`, building succeeds but the shared library is only a few kilobytes while the static library is about 3 megabytes... So it seems something went wrong in linking the static library. I have no idea what it could be. I am only using C++ code.

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := kes
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libkes.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := PortaKES
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PortaKES.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBARIES := kes

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

JNI directory structure:

[image: JNI folder structure]

Output:

```
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/PortaKES/PortaKES.o: In function `Java_com_kurzweil_portakes_KESFile_createPOLEFile':
C:\Users\niels.mylle\Documents\Kurzweil Mobile Android\PortaKES/jni/PortaKES.cpp:18: undefined reference to `CPoleFile::CPoleFile(char const*, bool, bool, CEncrypter*)'
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/PortaKES/PortaKES.o: In function `Java_com_kurzweil_portakes_KESFile_createKSection':
C:\Users\niels.mylle\Documents\Kurzweil Mobile Android\PortaKES/jni/PortaKES.cpp:33: undefined reference to `CKSection::CKSection(char const*, CPoleFile*, CPoleLeaf*)'
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/PortaKES/PortaKES.o: In function `Java_com_kurzweil_portakes_POLEFile_destroy':
C:\Users\niels.mylle\Documents\Kurzweil Mobile Android\PortaKES/jni/PortaKES.cpp:48: undefined reference to `CPoleFile::~CPoleFile()'
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/PortaKES/PortaKES.o: In function `Java_com_kurzweil_portakes_POLEFile_exists':
C:\Users\niels.mylle\Documents\Kurzweil Mobile Android\PortaKES/jni/PortaKES.cpp:100: undefined reference to `CPoleFile::exists(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libPortaKES.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's just part of the problem, but at least this reference is wrong:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libkes.a
```

You're building for all the ndk compatible architectures, but always referencing the same static prebuilt for each of them, which cannot work.

You should have a different .a for each architecture you're targeting, ie `./armeabi/libkes.a`, `./x86/libkes.a`, `./armeabi-v7a/libkes.a`, etc. In that case you'll be able to reference your .a using `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` variable, like so:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libkes.a
```

Comment: All right, after some work, It turned indeed out to be an architecture compatibility problem. After building the static library for each architecture, the undefined references were gone. Thanks!